# How to export only a subset of header-only boost libraries?

Tags: c++, boost

From the boost library, I only require circular_buffer for an android project (maybe some other later, but it will always be header-only). Thus, I would like to create a distribution containing only the required files.

I tried using the official distribution, and executing :

```
./bootstrap.sh --includedir=.. --with-libraries=circular_buffer
```

However, when I then execute :

```
./b2
```

It outputs :

```
error: wrong library name 'circular_buffer' in the --with-<library> option.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: For including C++ third party dependencies like this with stray build characteristics conan may be a good fit. You can pass header_only=True to options in conanfile.py or conanfile.txt and it'll trim the fat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap and b2 are only required for building library binaries. As you said, you will use header-only only, so that's not required.

You can just zip up the `boost/` include folders and be happy.

In theory you can prune the set of includes with BCP: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html

However, in practice I doubt it's worth the effort.